# Function to calculate Euclidean distance in c

Tags: c, floating-accuracy, euclidean-distance

I wrote function which calculates Euclidean distance. Return value of function  doesn't fit in required accuracy range. I made all the variables double which is the most accurate type and used `sqrt()` function which is for double not `sqrtf` and still the returned value is not proper. Here is my function:

```
float distance(const struct color_t* p1, const struct color_t* p2, int* err_code) {
        if (p1 == NULL || p2 == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }
     double r1 = 1, r2 = 1, r3 = 1, r4=1;
    double p11 = (double)p1->r - (double)p2->r;
    double p22 = (double)p1->g - (double)p2->g;
    double p33 = (double)p1->b - (double)p2->b;
    double p44 = (double)p1->a - (double)p2->a;
    for (int exponent = 2; exponent > 0; exponent--)
    {
        r1 = r1 * p11;
        r2 = r2 * p22;
        r3 = r3 * p33;
        r4 = r4 * p44;
    }
    double b = r1 + r2 + r3 + r4;
    double a = sqrt(b);
    if (a < 0) {
        return -1;
    }   
    return a;
}
```

Prompt is: Value 367.106262 returned by function distance() doesn't fit in required accuracy range.

and test:

```
struct color_t c1 = {.r = 14, .g = 253, .b = 23, .a = 76}, c2 = {.r = 253, .g = 14, .b = 148, .a = 6};

            printf("#####START#####");
            float dist = distance(&c1, &c2, NULL);
            printf("#####END#####\n");

            test_error(360.4206425334894 > dist && 360.3206425334894 < dist, "Value %f returned by function distance() doesn't fit in required accuracy range", dist);
```

Comment: Euclidian distance between what and what? Why does it require a loop? Can you please descirbe the algorithm you are trying to implement?

Comment: Was it right to consider the transparency component?

Comment: Anyway, why have you switched back to `float`? This `360.4206425334894 > dist` is comparing `double` with `float`.The `double` type is the "natural" size of floating point variables in C (although a particular application might need `float`).

Comment: Agree with @Weather:  You do all your calculations in `double`, then throw away all that accuracy when you return a `float`, which has less precision.

Comment: It's Euclidean distance between two colours: `p1`and `p2`. One colour consists of four components: `r`- value of red component, `g`- value of green component, `b`- value of blue component , `a`- value of transparency.

Comment: My function has to return float value, it's condition of the task.

Comment: Ok, I will try not to consider transparency component and see what happens.

Comment: I tried it by removing Alpha (`a`), and got the right answer: `360.370643`

Comment: You were right, I shouldn't have taken transparency under consideration.

Comment: I'd still drop the for loop and just directly assign `r1` through `r4` directly with the temp values times themselves 1 time.  No need for a confusing, backwards counting for loop there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Drop the transparent term**

[@abelenky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62138506/function-to-calculate-euclidean-distance-in-c#comment109899597_62138506)

OP is looking for the "distance" in color.

**`int` math fine for all but last step**

Largest value for `dist2` is 255*255*3 = 195,075, well within `float` exactly encodable range.

```
float distance(const struct color_t *p1, const struct color_t *p2, int *err_code /* unused */ ) {
  if (p1 == NULL || p2 == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }
  int p11 = p1->r - p2->r;
  int p22 = p1->g - p2->g;
  int p33 = p1->b - p2->b;
  int dist2 = p11*p11 + p22*p22 + p33*p33;
  return sqrtf(dist2);
}
```